# Why Does NOT this Ruby Overriden Method Get Called

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, inheritance, devise, passwords

I'm subclassing `Devise::PasswordsController`

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb

```
class MyPasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController

protected

  # Reference: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb
  def unlockable?(resource)
    v = resource.respond_to?(:unlock_access!) &&
      resource.respond_to?(:unlock_strategy_enabled?)
      # && resource.unlock_strategy_enabled?(:none) # sets to :none

puts "##############################"
puts v
puts "##############################"

    return v
  end
end
```

I also have the routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:passwords => :my_passwords}
```

I'm sure that `Devise::PasswordsController::update` is called, but why does not ruby pick up my `MyPasswordsController::unlockable?` method (it's supposed to be called in the `update` method?

**EDIT**

What I'm trying to say is the following code in C++. Is Ruby behaving differently?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void VirtualMethod()
    {
        cout << "Base::VirtualMethod" << endl;
        VirtualMethodSub();
    }

    virtual void VirtualMethodSub()
    {
        cout << "Base::VirtualMethodSub" << endl;
    }
};

class Dervied : public Base
{
    virtual void VirtualMethodSub()
    {
        cout << "Derived::VirtualMethodSub" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Dervied d;
    d.VirtualMethod();

    return 0;
}
/* Output:
Base::VirtualMethod
Derived::VirtualMethodSub
 */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I am using Devise 2.1.2, and the link:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb

is for the latest version Devise.

Answer (score 0):

You views hit PasswordsController#update. Not MyPasswordsController#update. So implement your own PasswordsController by extending from Devise::Passwords controller.

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  protected
  def unlockable?(resource)
  end
end
```

And in your config/routes.rb, Add

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:passwords => 'passwords'}
```

If your resource is not users, replace it with your resource name.

Comment: I already have the routes. Just to let you know that, if I override `Devise::PasswordsController::update`, it IS called, and my `unlockable?` is also called.  But I don't want to override `update`, because the `super::update` is what I need.